# Printing the alphabet between two user input letters

Tags: python

I want a program that prompts the user for two inputs for capital letters, and outputs their inclusive range all on the same line. I've worked on it and come out to this:

```
first = input("Please enter a capital letter: ")
second = input("Please enter another capital letter: ")
count = ord(first)
while count <= ord(second):
    print(chr(count))
    count = count + 1
```

This code will print the inclusive range of the user's first and second letter input, but they're not all on the same line, which is what I wanted. I was thinking I could possibly return the values to a list and output it that way, but I'm sure there's a simpler option?

Comment: DO NOT DUPLICATE your own question. Your original one was closed for good reason, this way you only waste time of other people.

Comment: My previous question was flagged for being too ambiguous. This one is far more specific, no?

Comment: You should edit your original question rather than repost it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print function has specific things for this. For your purpose, the function is `print("texthere", end = '')`

Answer (score 0):

Join the characters into a single string before printing them:

```
first = input("Please enter a capital letter: ")
second = input("Please enter another capital letter: ")

chars = [chr(ch) for ch in range(ord(first), ord(second)+1)]
print("".join(chars))
```

Answer (score 0):

a Pythonic way of doing it, can be the following.

```
>>> a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ"
>>> first =  input("Please enter a capital letter: ")
>>> second = input("Please enter another capital letter: ")
>>> if first < second:
>>>    print a[a.index(first): a.index(second)+1]
>>> else:
>>>    print a[a.index(second): a.index(first)+1]
>>>
```